# Is it possible to use the Tumblr API to search globally across Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I am looking at the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) but having trouble understanding whether it's possible to use it to search globally across Tumblr, rather than aiming it at a particular user?

Here is the information that I would like to collect:

- 10 or so most commented posts ever, globally across all users
- 10 or so most liked posts ever, globally across all users

Answer (score 1):

[Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#common-fields) provides

1. [Blog Methods](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog_methods) - information about the blog
2. [User Methods](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods) - user's account information
3. [Tagged Method](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method) - Get Posts with Tag

Tagged Methods fits your need for searching globally across Tumblr, rather than aiming it at a particular user.

However, Request Parameters and Responses specified in the Tumblr API does not support the condition that you are looking for.